# What inspired the vacuum tube train near the end?

Tags: realism, kingsman-the-secret-service

What inspired the vacuum tube train near the end of *Kingsman: The Secret Service*...was it the Scientific American article by L.K.Edwards 50 years ago? The one buried under New York made a brief appearance a few years ago in a Godzilla movie.

Answer (score 2):

When I saw the film I took it to have been inspired by [Mail Rail](http://www.mailrail.co.uk/).  This is the system under London that used to carry mailbags between the major rail termini and the Sorting Office at Mount Pleasant.

This was originally a pneumatic system:
[image: Pneumatic Mail Rail]
but later became a driverless electric railway - and no longer pneumatic:
[image: Electric Mail Rail]

The system was closed a few years ago and has now become one of London's more unusual tourist attractions.  You can ride on one of the old electric wagons, converted to take a couple of passengers.

A bit of disclosure; I wrote some of the software that controlled the electric system when it received an upgrade in the early 1990s.

*The pictures are on the linked website*